# Unable to connect MySql Using Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to connect to MySQL dB using spring boot. As Spring boot requires very less configuration I am not getting where I am going wrong. 
My Code Structure is Like,
I have main class which starts application,
A model Customer class,
A web Controller class.
A customer Repository Interface to implement CRUD operations.

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long>
{
     List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I am getting errors as:

```
ERROR 7740 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : 
Unable to create initial connections of pool

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could 
not create connection to database server,
and very long error messages.
```

Comment: Are you able to connect with the same credentials and from the same server otherwise (eg, using a mysql GUI utility or from the MySQL CLI)?

Comment: Yes I am able to connect to database using same id and password in Mysql workbench as well as From command prompt.

Answer (score 4):

It worked. Actually I am using spring boot parent version as 1.5.8 which is older and MYSQL with latest version as 8.0.11 which was causing compatibility issue. I just added version property in dependency of MySQL and it get connected.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
         <version>8.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```